# How to get JSON files one after other when each downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, async-await, getjson

I am trying to code a plugin that first,

1. it loads 2 json files, saves each in a variable,
2. then loads 2 more json files and saves them in variables,
3. Then run another function.

These three steps need to be done when the previous one is completed. The main reason is the information taken from previous step will be used in next step.

I have this code but does not work the way I want.

```
 $.when(parseJSON1(), parseJSON2())
  .then(
    parseJSON3(station_data.dj), parseJSON4(station_data.songurl)
  )
  .then(
    _cacheOptions
  )

  });

  var station_data, history_data, itunes_data, coverList_data;

  // Core Functions

  function _cacheOptions() {
    station_data = stationInfo[0];
    history_data = stationHistory[0];
    itunes_data = itunesInfo[0];
    coverList_data = coverInfo[0];
  }

  // Functions

  function parseJSON1() {
    return $.getJSON(settings.JSON1);
  }

  function parseJSON2() {
    return $.getJSON(settings.JSON2);
  }

  function parseJSON3(searchTerm) {
    return $.getJSON(settings.JSON3);
  }

  function parseJSON4() {
    return $.getJSON(settings.JSON4);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), the .then() method treats the two callbacks in its params as functions to call in case of success or failure/error, respectively. The way your code is written currently, it looks like you're telling it to:

- Get JSON1 and JSON2
- If those two calls resolve successfully, get JSON3
- If either call fails, get JSON4
- Then call _cacheOptions

Beyond that, it looks like there are some other issues:

- The data fetched in your .when() clause isn't getting passed to the two callbacks that require the information from that first step.
- The _cacheOptions function is referencing undefined variables *stationInfo, stationHistory, itunesInfo, coverInfo*

Assuming these four variables are the data fetched by parseJSON1 through 4, you could rewrite your code as:

```js
var stationInfo, stationHistory, itunesInfo, coverInfo; // to store the returned JSON data

var station_data, history_data, itunes_data, coverList_data; // set by _cacheOptions

// wait for getJSONs to resolve
$.when(parseJSON1(), parseJSON2()) 

  // use resolved data in next step
  .then(function(JSON1, JSON2) {

    // set your scoped vars
    stationInfo = JSON1;
    stationHistory = JSON2;

    // Then call the next two async fetches
    // Note that, since you already set your local vars with the returned data,
    // you don't need to pass anything to these functions, they can just
    // reference the info like the _cachOptions function
    return $.when(parseJSON3(), parseJSON4());
  })
  .then(function(JSON3, JSON4){

    // set your scoped vars
    itunesInfo = JSON3;
    coverInfo = JSON4;

    return _cacheOptions();
  })

// Core Functions
function _cacheOptions() {
  station_data = stationInfo[0];
  history_data = stationHistory[0];
  itunes_data = itunesInfo[0];
  coverList_data = coverInfo[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Great solution. Just one question. Would it be possible to tell me how the chain can continue? I mean have more than one function that have to run after the `_cacheOptions`. With my initial code, I tried it use `then()` for each. such as: `.then(
    _cacheOptions
  )
  .then(
    _cacheDom
  )
  .then(
    _events

  ).then(
    _render
  );`. So each function runs after another.

Comment: Yes, you can chain as many callbacks as you want this way using .then(). You can also check out async functions, which often let you do the same thing with more legible code. (see https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec1051 or https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)